# Null reference in C# Mono / GTK#

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

I am trying to create a simple note-taking application for my own use. The idea is to learn C#/Mono XML editing.

I can't find a NullReference that the compiler is complaining about. No idea why. I can't see it. After few days of searching I give up... help. :)

Here is the code that is making a bug. The application runs fine until I press a button to Add new note. It just crashes. The add_activated function runs when a button is pressed and it should use AddNote function.

The code is incomplete and it certainly has some logic bugs. But I can handle those. I'm just wondering why it won't run.

MainActivity.cs:

```
// (...)
protected void add_activated (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Gtk.TextBuffer buffer;          
        buffer = textview1.Buffer;

        Note note = new Note(entry3.Text, buffer.Text);     

        AddNote (note);
    }


    public static void AddNote (Note note)
    {
        string xmlFile = "/home/tomasz/.keeper/keeper.xml";

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument ();
        xmlDoc.Load (xmlFile);
        XmlNode xmlRoot = xmlDoc.CreateElement("keeper");

        if (!xmlDoc.DocumentElement.Name.Equals("keeper") )
        {       
            xmlDoc.AppendChild (xmlRoot);
        }

        XmlNode xmlNote = xmlDoc.CreateElement ("note");
        XmlNode xmlTitle = xmlDoc.CreateElement ("title");
        XmlNode xmlText = xmlDoc.CreateElement ("text");

        xmlRoot.InsertAfter (xmlRoot.LastChild, xmlNote);
        xmlTitle.InnerText = note.Title;
        xmlNote.InsertAfter (xmlNote.LastChild, xmlTitle);
        xmlText.InnerText = note.Text;
        xmlNote.InsertAfter (xmlNote.LastChild, xmlText);

        xmlDoc.Save (xmlFile);
    }


    protected void remove_activated (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException ();
    }
    }
}
```

Note.cs:

```
using System;

namespace Keeper
{
public class Note
{   
    private string title;
    private string text;

    public string Title {
        get 
        {
            return this.title;
        }
        set 
        {
            this.title = value;
        }
    }
    public string Text
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.text;
        }
        set 
        {
            this.text = value;
        }
    }

    public Note (string title, string text)
    {
        this.Title = title;
        this.Text = text;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should post the full message given by runtime.

Comment: Did you try to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate problem is that you got the arguments to `InserAfter` mixed up. First one should be the node to insert and the second one should be the reference node. The root element has no children yet, so `LastChild` is going to be `null` and hence the exeption. Using `null` as a reference point is valid, but not as a node to add.

There are other issues but you said you are able to fix those, so there you go.